converting curl to RestAssured
I am executing an http request from Java (via Eclipse).  I got it to work fine using curl, but that is calling a windows program from Java and it would be nice to do it with Rest Assured.  My command is
 String curl = "c:\windows\System32\curl.exe -X DELETE http://my.url.com/file-attachment-service/dir/serv?myId=240930203172014&sysId=66fa8cdacfd6f35800f44cbe&userId=XXX.YYY&userSysKey=xxxx";

(URL and service name changed for proprietary reasons).  The Java I use to execute this, which works fine, is
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(curl);
Integer exitCode2 = p.waitFor(); 

Then I check the exit code to be sure.
I have tried several things with Rest Assured but I always get something like "connection refused".  Does anyone have an algorithm or so for converting a curl command to Rest Assured?

Can you share what have you tried with Rest Assured?

Yes, I will answer soon

Do you need an automatic converter or you need to convert this particular expression?

Still looking for the code.  I need one for this expression, BUT I can foresee in the future needing something again (something different)

I can't write a comment. Have you tried
adding this dependency :
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
</dependency>

then
    RestAssured.baseURI = "http://my.url.com";

    RestAssured.given()
            .queryParam("myId", "1")
            .queryParam("sysId", "66")
            .queryParam("userId", "XXX.YYY")
            .queryParam("userSysKey", "xxxx")
            .when()
            .delete("/file-attachment-service/dir/serv")
            .then()
            .statusCode(200); // Check for the expected status code


I have the dependency.  I will try your suggestion
